# Java: Logging in to a website using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

First let me point out that I'm very new to programming so if I'm missing something obvious, I'm sorry.

I'm trying to write a program that lets you log in to [this website](https://www.skanetrafiken.se/inloggning?ReturnUrl=%2Fmitt-konto%2Fse-saldo-och-ladda-kort%2F)
but I'm having trouble figuring out how to input my own strings to the email and password fields. I'm also not quite sure on how to check if the login went through or not...

This is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String loginURL = "https://www.skanetrafiken.se/inloggning?ReturnUrl=%2fmitt-konto%2fse-saldo-och-ladda-kort%2f"; // URL of the login page
    String accountURL = "https://www.skanetrafiken.se/mitt-konto/se-saldo-och-ladda-kort/"; // The URL you get to after successfully logging in

    Document res = Jsoup
            .connect(loginURL)
            .data("loginInputModel.Email", "myEmail@email.com") //Not sure if these are the correct values to be changed or if this even changes them
            .data("loginInputModel.Password", "myPassword")
            .post();

    System.out.println(res); // What should be printed to check to see if it worked?
}
```

It's similar to a lot of the examples I've seen but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: what is the output of println?

Comment: Oh... it's just the HTML for the login page... EDIT: Changing it to System.out.println(Jsoup.connect(accountURL).get()); produces the same result though...

Comment: there is a "." in the "loginInputModel.Password" shouldn't it be  "loginInputModel_Password"?

Comment: Whoops, silly, you're right, but it still doesn't let me log in...

Comment: is there any error on the "res" html? any message like invalid username or password?

Comment: The edit you made, you changed underscore to "." but I meant the other way around. I saw the login page and the data have underscore

Comment: I'm seeing a javascript internalServerErrorMessage that says (translated) "Something went wrong, please try again later. You can also contact customer service for more information".

I've tried both "." and "_" in the loginInputModels, neither work...

Comment: try this for loginURL: "h ttps://www.skanetrafiken.se/inloggning/LoginPost/?ReturnUrl=%2fmitt-konto%2fse-saldo-och-ladda-kort%2f"

Comment: Ok, so when I paste that into the adress bar it produces a 404 page, and when I use it as loginURL it outputs a HTML saying I have the wrong username or password (which i'm 100% sure I don't).

Comment: The URL that I posted is from the source of your site, if you look into the source code you will find it. There is a form that its action is set to "/inloggning/LoginPost/". have you also tried with the "." version?

Comment: Yeah, tried both "." and "underscore", only difference being that "underscore" produces two error messages telling me I have the wrong username or password whilst "." only produces one, could it have something to do with the password field having "type="password"" instead of "type="text"" like the username field does?

Answer (score 2):

For a site that supports HTTP basic access authentication you can access any page by sending the Authorization header in a request. Your site supports it and code could be following to  access account page:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // We need run initial request to obtain RequestVerificationToken
        String initialURL = "https://www.skanetrafiken.se/inloggning";
        Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(initialURL)
                .get();

        String requestVerificationToken = doc.select("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").get(0).val();

        // Do login (all headers and more  important all  form fields should be populated)
        String loginURL = "https://www.skanetrafiken.se/inloggning/LoginPost/";
        Response res = Jsoup.connect(loginURL)
                .header("Accept", "*/*")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
                .header("Origin", "https://www.skanetrafiken.se")
                .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                .header("Referer", "https://www.skanetrafiken.se/inloggning")
                .data("__RequestVerificationToken", requestVerificationToken)
                .data("loginInputModel.ReturnUrl", "")
                .data("loginInputModel.Role", "Private")
                .data("loginInputModel.Email", "<email>")
                .data("loginInputModel.Password", "<password>")
                .data("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();

        // Keep logged in (store cookies for next calls)
        Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

        // Request a desired page
        String accountURL = "https://www.skanetrafiken.se/mitt-konto/se-saldo-och-ladda-kort/";
        Document doc2 = Jsoup
                .connect(accountURL)
                .cookies(cookies)
                .get();

        // Work with the doc
        System.out.println(doc2);
    }
}
```